# Is it better to partition a virtual hard drive in VirtualBox?

Tags: partitioning, windows, virtualbox

I am installing Windows 8.1 under VirtualBox Under Ubuntu 14.04.

Is it better to partition the virtual hard drive for Windows into system and user data, just to separate them as if I would install Windows on a metal machine?

I have specified the shared folder between the virtual machine for Windows and the host OS (Ubuntu 14.04). Is it good to store all my data used by Windows in the shared folder, and therefore no need to partition the virtual drive and give it all to Windows system?

Thanks.

Comment: Since its all virtual, why not a separate virtual disk for data rather than a virtual partition within the same virtual disk? Then you can copy the second virtual disk elsewhere as a backup.

Comment: Can I add the second virtual disk later after installing Windows?

Comment: @Tim Yes, you can add it anytime you want.